# Test to see if all elements of list/variable are true

Tags: prolog

I'm writing an adviser program that selects classes for students to take next semester.  One of the tasks is to check if the student has all of the prerequisites.  So far, I've got:

```
hasPrereqs(Student, Class) :-
    (prereq(Pre, Class) -> 
        hasClass(Student, Pre);
    true).

hasClass(Student, Class) :-
    (creditFor(Student, Class);
    currentlyTaking(Student, Class)).
```

prereqs are declared as such:

```
prereq(csc140, csc145).
prereq(csc140, csc180).
prereq(csc140, csc198).
prereq([csc140, csc130], csc201).
prereq(csc145, csc201).
```

This works for every possibility except when two classes are required for another class (as in `csc201`, where a student can take either csc140 AND csc130 OR just csc140).  I think lists are the way to go, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

I've tried creating another `hasPrereqs` as follows:

```
hasPrereqs(Student, Class) :-
forall(prereq(Pre, Class),
(compound(Pre) -> 
    hasClass(Student, Pre)).
```

This one won't work because `Pre` is a list, rather than a straight atom and thus:

```
creditFor(somekittens, csc130).
creditFor(somekittens, csc140).
/* Returns false, because I don't have credit for the list, just the two classes */
creditFor(somekittens, [csc130, csc140]).
```

How can I set up the system so that classes requiring several other classes just work?

Comment: Some suggestions: `prereq/2`: Put all prerequired classes into a list. Even if there is only a single one. Even if there is none - which would be an empty list.

Comment: How would that be an advantage over the way I'm currently doing it?  (Also, great username, especially for Prolog questions.)

Comment: It would be more uniform (no longer special casing)- and it would solve your problem with alternative prerequisites smoothly.

Comment: Have you seen my solution below?  It doesn't use special cases like `compound/1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
hasPrereqs(Student, Class) :-
  prereq(Class, Pres),
  forall(member(Pre, Pres), hasClass(Student, Pre)).

hasClass(Student, Class) :-
  (creditFor(Student, Class);
  currentlyTaking(Student, Class)).

prereq(csc140, []).
prereq(csc145, [csc140]).
prereq(csc180, [csc140]).
prereq(csc198, [csc140]).
prereq(csc201, [csc140, csc130]).
prereq(csc201, [csc145]).
```

I made swapped the order of arguments on `prereq/2` and made the prerequisites a list regardless how many there are.  This makes code using `prereq/2` more consistent and gives you a notation for classes that have no prerequisite, namely `prereq(foo, [])`.

I then used `forall/2` and `member/2` to make sure the student has met all the prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who's coming from a functional programming background (like me!) wants to do this:

```
foreach(var i=0;i<Class.length;i++) {
    if(!hasClass(Student, Class[i])) {
         return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  There's no easy way (to my knowledge) to traverse a list in Prolog and return `true` IFF all the elements returned true.  Rather, use a recursive method to traverse the list.  Add another definition for `hasClass` like this:

```
hasClass(Student, ClassList) :-
    /* Splits up the list into:
    H = the first element of the list as an atom
    T = The rest of the list elements as a list
    (if there's only one list element, T is equal to []) */
    [H|T] = ClassList,
    hasClass(Student, H),
    /* if T isn't equal to [], recursively check the rest of the list's elements */
    (T \= [] -> hasClass(Student, T);true).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hasPrereqs(Student, Class) :-
    (prereq(Pre, Class) -> 
        hasClass(Student, Pre);
    true).
```

is **always** true, irrespective of variables instancing and the actual factual data you have.
The only purpose could be some side effect (like IO or DB modification) performed by prereq/2 or hasClass/2, and this doesn't appears to be.

Now to the answer. SWI-prolog has [is_list](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=is_list/1)/1 and [maplist](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29)/2, the latter can repeat the same test on each element, being true only if the test succeed on all elements:

**edit** Class was meant to be Pre

```
hasPrereqs(Student, Class) :-
 forall(prereq(Pre, Class),
   (   is_list(Pre)
   ->  maplist(hasClass(Student), Pre)
   ;   hasClass(Student, Pre)
   )).
```

or better, if you plan to reuse hasClass only for test, and assuming an already working hasClass/2

```
hasPrereqs(Student, Class) :-
   forall(prereq(Pre, Class), hasClass(Student, Pre)).

hasClass(Student, Classes) :-
   is_list(Classes) -> maplist(hasClass(Student), Classes).
```

**edit** the following is buggy, looping on last call...

Yet another way. In your answer, you were near to the solution:

```
hasClass(Student, ClassList) :-
    (   [H|T] = ClassList
    ->  hasClass(Student, H), hasClass(Student, T)
    ;   hasClass(Student, ClassList)
    ).
```

**edit** the solution should be simpler:

```
hasClass(Student, [Class|ClassList]) :-
    hasClass(Student, Class),
    !, hasClass(Student, ClassList).
hasClass(_Student, []).
```